# Is it possible to track ios device?

Tags: iphone, ios, google-maps, tracking

Is it possible to track any iOS devices using PhoneNumber or UDID or IMEI number to show the device in google map. please help me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to track phone location using IMEI number and gps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14395427/how-to-track-phone-location-using-imei-number-and-gps)

Answer (score 3):

Install "Find my iPhone" and use iCloud. My wife uses this to see where I am when I'm out on my bike. And I use it to ping the iPhone when I lose it around the house.

Answer (score 1):

I am sure you can't get the iPhone's IMEI without using a private framework and if you do so you will be automatically rejected.
        Usually, when mobile developpers wants some unique ids, the solution is to ask the user's email address. If you really want to differentiate users devices, you can create some random UDID that you save in the app preferences.